# Should I install node.js modules through npm install only?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is that any difference `npm install` and just move whole module folders? In fact, I'm trying to deploy my node app to linux server, but there is some problem with `npm install` so I move my node_modules folder entirely to linux server, apparently no problem with it.

Is it possible to be troubled this way later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` doesn't just copy code from the Internet to node_modules. The installation might also compile code for the platform.

So if you are copying from/to the same platform it should be OK. Though even then some modules might not work depending on the environments.

Answer (score 0):

npm install read package.json and install all missing modules in node_modules folder. There is no problem if you just copied node_modules folder from your source.

But if you want to install any new module then use:
     **npm install package-name --save (or -g if you want to install globally)** so that your package.json can track new modules.